# Python introspection - how to check current module / line of call from within function

Tags: python, introspection

I have a function:

```
# utils.py
def hello(name='World'):
    # Detect where I'm being called from.
    print('Hi, %s. You called this from %s at line # %d.' % (name, mod, lineno))
    # ``mod`` and ``lineno`` on previous line would have been set in real use.
```

I import that function and run it elsewhere

```
# other.py (this comment at line # 138)
from utils import hello
hello('Johnny')  # From inside ``hello`` I want to be able to detect that this
# was called from other.py at line # 140
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Access the enclosing frame of `inspect.currentframe()`:

```
import inspect

def hello(name='World'):
    f = inspect.currentframe().f_back
    mod = f.f_code.co_filename
    lineno = f.f_lineno
    print('Hi, %s. You called this from %s at line # %d.' %
          (name, mod, lineno))
```

Answer (score 3):

The `traceback` module lets you extract the stack, so you can see how you reached the current stack frame. If you want you can extend this to print the caller-of-caller, as far up the stack as you like:

```
import traceback

def _trace():
    stack = traceback.extract_stack()[-3:-1]
    path, line, in_func, _instr = stack[0]
    print 'called from %s in func %s at line %s' % (path, in_func, line)

def bar():
    _trace()

def foo():
    bar()
    baz()

def baz():
    bar()

bar()
foo()
```

Output:

```
called from hello.py in func <module> at line 20
called from hello.py in func foo at line 14
called from hello.py in func baz at line 18
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`warnings`](http://docs.python.org/library/warnings) module.

```
import warnings

def test(where):
    warnings.warn('hi from test', stacklevel=2)

def foo():
    test('inside foo')

test('from main module')
foo()
```

Results:

```
/tmp/test.py:9: UserWarning: hi from test
  test('from main module')
/tmp/test.py:7: UserWarning: hi from test
  test('inside foo')
```

Check the line numbers. Using the `warnings` module is great because the user of your module can disable warnings, or turn them into fully inspectable exceptions.